# highcharts mapchart: no color shown after reload the graph

Tags: highcharts

I am new to high charts.

Below is my partial code in a function when creating a mapChart, what it does is that it only show the matching region (with cur_state) as red and others as blue.

```
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    map: 'countries/au/au-all',
                    events: {
                        load: function () {
                            // place1
                            this.series[0].data = this.series[0].data.map((el) => {
                                // place2
                                if (el['hc-key'] == region_dict[cur_state][1]) {
                                    el.color = "#ff0000";
                                    return el;
                                }
                                el.color = "blue"
                                return el
                            })

                            this.update({
                                series: [{
                                    data: this.series[0].data
                                }]
                            })
                        }
                    }
                },
```

When the value of cur_state is changed, I recall the function which contains the map graph, hoping that the corresponding region has color update.

This is the first time I call the function:

[image]

This is after second time I call the function, the coloring and hovering effect are gone:
[image]

After testing, I realised that both place1 and place2 are executed when the chart is firstly created, and only place1 is executed when the chart is re-created.

My other part of code has similar structure as this: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/au/au-all

How can I achieve the expected outcome?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution in your case seems to be to use render event and change the color on the SVG level. Example:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                this.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
                    if (point['hc-key'] == state) {
                        point.graphic.attr({
                            fill: 'red'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x69pLcyo/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah it works. But you have the hovering effect ("green" colour) in my code. After moving my mouse to the "red" state, the state turns "green", but when my mouse leaves the state, the colour turns to the default "blue". How can I avoid this?

Comment: Hi @Yige Song, You are right, please additionally add `point.color = 'red';`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5z3g8ko/